# Fatal error explanation?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm getting this fatal error message:

> Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in C:\wamp\www\mySite\application\controllers\eventsManager.php on line 115

Could someone tell me what it means?

The line it refers to is this:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('alert') = '<ul>'.validation_errors('<li>','</li>').'</ul>';
```

Comment: What's `$this->session->set_flashdata('alert')` doing?
The error usually means you have to store value returned from a function before you can assign any values to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line should be:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('alert', '<ul>'.validation_errors('<li>','</li>').'</ul>');
```

Comment: Ofcourse. Me just being dumb. Thanks for being a fresh set of eyes, Phil. ps just downloaded pyro-cms and loving what I'm seeing so far...

Answer (score -1):

From a quick google search, I have gathered that the empty() function may be the culprit. It isn't in your code but it may be in set_flashdata() somewhere. empty() can only check a variable, not the return value of a function. Assign `validation_errors('<li>','</li>')` to at temp variable and insert the temp var instead.